# Wordpress categories in combobox

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, categories

Hi I want to show second dropdown menu when I click on category from the first one, and I want to populate it with child categories from that selected one from the first dropdown.

```
<li id="categories">
<h2><?php _e( 'Posts by Category' ); ?></h2>

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none' => __( 'Select category' ),
        'show_count'       => 1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',

    );
    ?>

<?php wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'show_option_none' => __( 'Select category' ),
                    'show_count'       => 1,
                    'orderby'          => 'name',
                    'child_of'         => 3
                     );
                echo wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>

        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
    -->
</script>
```

When I use this line instead of php block in onCatChange function :

```
location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

It navigates to appropriate post so the code works with linking posts but why it does not show me that second dropdown when I put my php code. And in this example I hardcoded child of on number 3 just in purpose of testing. Thank you.

Comment: you do know js cannot pass values to php? All php will do is output the result so all you have is html inside a js function, wont do anything. You would be better off to show the html output instead of the php function and then try replace the select box with the output

Comment: @David I know that Js can not pass the value but I'm not sure that I'm following you, what is html output and how to replace select box with it ? Can you please give me an example or explain a little bit more. Thank you,